# How to change color of floating action button on theme change?

Tags: java, android, android-theme, color-scheme, floating-action-button

I want to apply different themes to my application. I want to change the color of navigation bar and floating action button.

Now I am able to change color of navigation bar , but floating action button's color dose not get change. How can I change color of fab dynamically when theme is changed?

Style:

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorAccent_500">@color/accent_500</item>
        <item name="colorAccent_700">@color/accent_700</item>

        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_material_light</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    <style name="BlueTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#03A9F4</item>

        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_material_light</item>
    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme.Solarized">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange300</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/orange500</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/solarizedOrange</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/solarizedBase01</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/solarizedBase1</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

Fab :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_fab"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/myfab_shadow"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/fab_shadow"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgbtn_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/fab_selector"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_36dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@animator/fab_elevation_selector" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Fab selector :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/accent_700" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/accent_500" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Thank you..

Comment: Change color value of accent color from color.xml file

Answer (score 2):

The floating action button is colored based on your **colorAccent**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Or from code:

```
fab.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.blue));
```

Or from XML:

Change attribute of **app:backgroundTint**

But it seems that you are using **ImageButton** not **FloatingActionButton**, You should use:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />
```

And in the dependencies add:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: colors for fab is set in fab selector. How can I change color there?

Comment: for this to work he needs to replace the custom fab layout with a <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton/> Example: https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/samples/SupportDesignDemos/res/layout/design_fab.xml

Comment: it seems that you are using ImageButton not FloatingActionButton, See the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answers. But I just changed in fab selector.

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />

    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

This worked..

Answer (score -1):

Please use the material shape theme with the floating button, its very easy now no need for customization